# I need colorbox to close when the external script is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, colorbox, surveymonkey

I am using colorbox to display a surveymonkey embedded survey as a workaround to popup blockers. Everything works perfectly until they complete the survey and return to the site. The colorbox pops up again displaying no content. I need to find a way to verify that there is no data between the script tags then close it or ONLY display it if there is content. I used firebug on the page, both before and after they survey was complete:

Before:

```
<script src="https://www.surveymonkey.com/jsPop.aspx?sm=4GSXwWYQ306AtiO3hP45Jg_3d_3d">
 document.write("<iframe id=\"sm_e_s\" src=\"https://www.surveymonkey.com/s.aspx?sm=4GSXwWYQ306AtiO3hP45Jg%3d%3d\" width=\"500\" height=\"1000\" style=\"border:0px;padding-bottom:4px;\" frameborder=\"0\" allowtransparency=\"true\" ><a href=\"https://www.surveymonkey.com/s.aspx?sm=4GSXwWYQ306AtiO3hP45Jg%3d%3d\">Please take our survey</a></iframe></script>");if(document.getElementById('surveyMonkeyInfo')) {document.getElementById('surveyMonkeyInfo').style.width='500px';document.getElementById('surveyMonkeyInfo').style.fontSize='10px';document.getElementById('surveyMonkeyInfo').style.color='#666';}
</script>
<iframe id="sm_e_s" height="1000" frameborder="0" width="500" allowtransparency="true" style="border:0px;padding-bottom:4px;" src="https://www.surveymonkey.com/s.aspx?sm=4GSXwWYQ306AtiO3hP45Jg%3d%3d">
</iframe>
```

(i left out some of the iFrame script as it was very lengthy and unnecessary)

After:

```
<script src="https://www.surveymonkey.com/jsPop.aspx?sm=4GSXwWYQ306AtiO3hP45Jg_3d_3d">
</script>
```

It seems like there should be a simple solution to this, but i just cant seen to put my finger on it!

EDIT:
here is whats in the HEAD, if i could figure out a way of checking if there is anything within the script tags, then i could prevent the colorbox from loading at the beginning:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/colorbox/colorbox.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, href:"#inline_content", open:true,});
        });

    </script>
```

EDIT2:
I'm back again! so JRods suggestion helped to stop the colorbox from running while the script tags were empty (which is exactly what i asked for, so thank you!) but i had never considered the hierarchy of when the scripts would run. If we check if the tags are empty before they execute, then they will always be empty and so the colorbox will never open the #inline_content . Does anyone have a suggestion of a way to run the script, check it, then run colorbox around it?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I seem to be having a rough day. My fiddle dosnt seem to like me either:
http://jsfiddle.net/j7C6W/2/
Heres the Live Site address, with your suggestion commented out for testing:
http://www.wtrrentals.com/indexTEST2.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Give your script tag a unique id.

```
<script id="myscript" src="https://www.surveymonkey.com/jsPop.aspx?sm=4GSXwWYQ306AtiO3hP45Jg_3d_3d">
</script>
```

Then you can use jquery's `html()` and `length` to see if there is anything inside the tag

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        if ( $('#myscript').html().length !== 0 ) {
            $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, href:"#inline_content", open:true,});
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks JRod! At first it wasnt working for me, then i realized i had a space between the script tags! i deleted it and it worked!